# How do you create a logic loop for reading and summing data from a file?

Tags: java, loops, logic

I'm working on a Java homework assignment that requires reading data from a supplied text file, manipulating the data to consolidate it into data for individual states, and then putting that data into an output file.  I don't know how to sum the data (I'm still dealing with partial pseudo-code so I'm not even to the point of trying to compile and addressing compiler errors).

A sample of the data in the incoming file is:

> 01 00190 Alabaster City School District                                              31754     6475      733 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
>   01 00005 Albertville City School District                                            21522     4010     1563 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
>   01 00030 Alexander City City School District                                         17292     2719     1158 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
>   01 00060 Andalusia City School District                                               9044     1512      471 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
>   01 00090 Anniston City School District                                               22759     3304     1122 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
>   06 21060 Lassen Union High School District                                           25961     1155      141 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
>   06 21090 Lassen View Union Elementary School District                                 2805      321       68 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014
>   06 21150 Laton Joint Unified School District                                          3824      818      263 USSD13.txt 24NOV2014

I can create a BufferedReader to read to file and was pointed in the direction of readLine to parse the individual elements of the lines that I wanted.  But I can't figure out how to sum up the columns for individual states, stopping when one state's data ends and starting over when another state's data starts.  Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ManipulateData
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        // Decalre variables that will be used multiple times
        int i = 0;  // i will be used as a counter

        // Ensure a file is called from the terminal and an output file 
        // is specified
        if (args.length != 2)
        {
            System.out.print("Expected command line entry is: ");
            System.out.print("java ManipulateData inputFile outputFile");
            return;
        }

        // Open the input file
        try
        {
            BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + exception.getMessage());
        }

        // Read the data from the file
        // First, get the number of lines in the file
        int lines = 0;
        while (fin.readLine() != null) lines++;

        int totalLines = lines
        String [] fileLines = new String [totalLines]; // May not need this

        // Read the lines from the file into Strings and store Strings in arrays
        for (i = 0; i < totalLines; i++);
        {
            String lineOfData = BufferedReader.readLine();
            // pull individual data points from lineOfData
            int state = Integer.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(0,1));
            int population = Integer.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(82,89));
            int childPopulation = Interger.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(91,98));
            int childPovertyPopulation = Integer.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(100-107));
            // Sum data for individual state
            stateNew = state;

        // Second, get the number of states in the file
        //not sure how to find number of states
        int numStates = 0;

        // Create arrays to hold data parsed from the file
        // int [] data = new int [lines][lines][lines][lines];
        int [] states = new int [numStates]; 
        int [] pop = new int [lines];
        int [] childPop = new int [lines];
        int [] childPovPop = new int [lines];

        try
        {
            do
            {
            ReadLine for next line

            Check if State = character positions 1-2

            a.  If true:

                1.  sumPop = sumPop + pop[i]
                2.  sumChildPop = sumChildPop + childPop[i]
                3.  sumChildPovPop = sumChildPovPop + childPovPop[i]

            b.  If false:

                1.  Set state1Pop = sumPop
                2.  Set state1ChildPop = sumChildPop
                3.  Set state1ChildPovPop = sumChildPovPop
                4.  Set state1PercentChildPovPop = sumChildPovPop / sumChildPop
                5.  Set all sum values back to 0
                6.  Start loop again for next state   
            }
            while (n != -1);
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading file.");
        }

        // Close the original file
        try
        {
            fin.close();
        }
        catch (IOException iOException)
        {
            System.out.println("Error closing file.");
        }

        // Write the output file
        try
        {
            BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
            fileOut.write("State   Population   Child Population Child Poverty Population  % Child Poverty");
            fileOut.write("-----   ----------   ---------------- ------------------------  ---------------");
            for (i = 0, i < numStates, i++);
            fileOut.write("   " + state + "    " + popSum + "          " + childPopSum + "             " + childPovPopSum + "

    }
}
```

So, to keep the question from getting lost amidst the total lack of comprehension presented, how do I loop through the 3000+ lines of code in the incoming file to make sure that I only add the data for state 01 to state 01 items then start over and only add state 02 data together, etc?

Comment: Create a plain old Java object/class to represent a single state and the data that it holds, create a collection (`ArrayList<MyState>` could work well), and then in the loop add MyStates to your collection and update a MyState object if the collection already has one.

Comment: As seems to be the case, everyone likes to go to ArrayLists.  But also as seems to be the case with homework, they aren't allowed: "The programs should not use any Java collections (ArrayList, Map, Vector, etc.) except standard Java arrays.  Collections are introduced in a later module."

Comment: They are just so darn flexible, but if you are not allowed to use them, then don't. You're stuck using an array, but again an array of your POJO (plain old Java Object) a class that holds the information of a single State. You'll have to declare the array to be large enough to hold all the states you'll possibly find, and you'll need to declare your array **before** your loop where you read in the data, but otherwise the techniques are much the same.

Comment: One of the problems I have is coming up with a method for seeing how many states there are.  The data doesn't go nicely from 1 - 50; it has gaps and has numbers beyond 50.  I need a way to do a comparison of state[i] to state[i+1] and to either sum the data if they are the same or to save the last sum off and start over at zero if they are different.  I can't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: You can create an array that is at least as big or bigger than the largest "state number", or you can create an array that is at least as big or bigger than the largest number of states present, and then not use the state number as the index to your array but rather make it a field of State class, up to you how you do this. Looping through your array to see if the state exists should be easy to do with either technique. But again first you need to create your class that holds a State's information.

Comment: Why would I need a class for a State's info beyond the main() class?  Wouldn't an array in main() be sufficient for storing the info?

Comment: Yes, but an array of ***WHAT***? An array of Strings? The information is hard to extract update and very hackish. An array of ints? but then you lose all the text info from the file....

Comment: Ah, I see -- you're using parallel arrays instead of a single array of subject. That's an "anti-pattern", something that should be avoided as it leads to very brittle (easily broken) code.

Comment: Thanks, @HovercraftFullOfEels, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of hours with a friend going over the problem.  The problem I couldn't wrap my head around was how to catch when the data changed from one state to another.  That path wasn't viable.  Instead, use the state code as the index, i.e. State 01 would be index 0, State 02 would be index 1, etc and all the data from the readLine for that state would be associated with the correct array index.

```
  // Creates a two-dimensional array.  First dimension will be for the state value
            int[][] dataPerState = new int[56][3];
            for (int k = 0; k < 56; ++k) {
                dataPerState[k][0] = 0;
                dataPerState[k][1] = 0;
                dataPerState[k][2] = 0;
            }

            try {
                // Open the input file
                BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

                // Read data from the input file
                // First, get the number of lines in the file
                int totalLines = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

                // Read the lines from the file into Strings and store Strings in arrays
                for (int i = 0; i < totalLines; i++)
                {
                    String lineOfData = fileIn.readLine();

                    // Pull individual data points from lineOfData
                    int state = Integer.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(0, 2).trim());
                    int population = Integer.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(82, 90).trim());
                    int childPopulation = Integer.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(91, 99).trim());
                    int childPovertyPopulation = Integer.parseInt(lineOfData.substring(100, 108).trim());

                    // Don't need to check to make sure state didn't change.
                    // Just use the state value as the index value for the 
                    // first dimension of the 2D array.  The summing follows
                    // naturally afterwards.
                    dataPerState[state - 1][0] += population;
                    dataPerState[state - 1][1] += childPopulation;
                    dataPerState[state - 1][2] += childPovertyPopulation;
                }

                // Close the input file
                fileIn.close();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.out.println("I/O Error: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
```